# Cartesian velocity control of robot arm

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 6DOF robot arm, and would like to start driving the end effector around with a joystick.  I think the most natural way to do this would be to map my joystick axes to Cartesian velocities of the end effector.  I have tried executing very small paths in the desired directions using `MoveGroupCommander.compute_cartesian_path()`, but I end up getting very jumpy results.  Are there any facilities built into MoveIt or otherwise to help me do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202206/cartesian-velocity-control-of-robot-arm/) by [rand](https://answers.ros.org/users/2393/rand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I actually found a good solution to this in the code for [pr2_teleop_general](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_apps/blob/hydro-devel/pr2_teleop_general/src/pr2_teleop_general_commander.cpp#L896). The basic idea is to:

1. Grab the current robot state using `RobotCommander.get_current_state()`
2. Call the `GetPositionFK` service of your `move_group` to get the the end effector position using this state as input.
3. Scale your Cartesian velocity by a constant and add it onto this position. Call the `GetPositionIK` service of your `move_group` to get an inverse kinematics solution for this.
4. Subtract your current joint angles from the IK joint angles, and multiply by some constant to get a velocity for every joint.

---

Originally posted by [rand](https://answers.ros.org/users/2393/rand/) with karma: 38 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sangfuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4080/sangfuu/) on 2015-04-07**:
rand, did this method worked for you or did you find something else?
I am trying to do the same thing with my 7DOF robot. Thanks